# VideoView Inside Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

**I am trying to put video view inside navigation drawer. VideoView working fine but freezing when navigation drawer move quickly and also videoview not moving quickly with navigation drawer. Is any ideo to fix this????? please help :::**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my my activity::::**

```
public class MainAct extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vid);
    VideoView videoView= (VideoView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 
    videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/x.mp4");
    videoView.start();  

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the drawerListener on your navigation drawer and pause and resume the videoview based on drawer state. Something like this should work:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myVideoView.pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myVideoView.resume();
        }
    });
```